# how to turn a git clone --reference into a standalone clone?

Tags: git

My CI server is handing me a directory that was created with git clone --reference; however, I'd like to turn this into a full local copy, because I'm going to mount it in a docker container that won't have access to the referenced repo.

Is there an in-place way to take a reference clone and turn it into an ordinary clone?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing directly in-place, no.

Clone the clone, with `--dissociate` if necessary (if using a local cloning protocol that would normally share objects—if using `file://` URLs or any over-the-net URLs, there will be no need for `--dissociate`).

Consider using `git clone --mirror` to create the dissociated clone with all branches existing, but remember that this makes a bare clone.  You can turn the bare clone back into a full clone afterward.  Or, do the clone with `--no-checkout`, then create local branch names from each remote-tracking branch name in the resulting clone.  (It's not really clear to me which of these is easier; they both require about the same amount of fixup work after cloning.)